# Creating a URL (and not necessarily a parameter list) using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, url

I am communicating to a REST server which is expecting something like `http://example.com/1.0/editor/5/bla/26` along with body parameters of `x`, `y`, and `z`.  Or maybe instead of `/1.0/editor/5/bla/26`, it should be `1.0/editor/5/bla/what about item #26`, but of course with `what about item #26` escaped.

There are many post describing how to use [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to encode parameters, however, that is not my question.  How chould the actual url be created using jQuery of JavaScript?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'PUT',
    url:'/1.0/editor/'+$('#id').val()+'/bla/'+$('#wha').data('id'),
    data:{x:x,y:y,z:z},
    success: function (error){}
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? URLs are strings, so string concatenation is a standard way of creating them.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  So, an unescaped url of `1.0/editor/use number 5!/bla/what about item #2` is okay?

Comment: No, you'd need to escape/encode them, as you already said. To encode strings in a URI, you'd use encodeURIComponent() on the string. See the duplicate.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  I don't think `encodeURIComponent()`, but just `encodeURI()`.  Maybe  `encodeURI('1.0/editor/use number 5!/bla/what about item #2')`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a javascript RegEx function to replace all spaces with a known character? Or replace it with its HTML equivalent. Then in your backend, just look for that escape character and replace them with the spaces again. It's kind of a work around but depending on your situation it could work.